# navigate between class members in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How to navigate between class members in visual C# 2010? I am so used to Ctrl up and down to do this in other IDEs. Is there something similar in this and how do I change it?

Page up and page down is slow and annoying if methods are of different sizes..

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ctrl + F2 and use the dropdownlists at the top of your editor to navigate between classes and members you are writing. After Ctrl + F2, use Tab to switch between dropdownlists and after selecting item hit Enter for going to the selected member.

Cheers

Comment: that is cumbersome. I wonder if there is shortcut to navigate up and down between methods and go to start of method from somewhere in between